# Backbone collection.add - Get instance of model(s) added

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Given I add a model to a collection:

```
ducks.add({ name: 'Ugly', role: 'Storytelling' });
```

Is there any way to get a hold of the instance of the added model(s) from the add?

```
// This doesn't work.
var ugly = ducks.add({ name: 'Ugly', role: 'Storytelling' });
ugly.flyAway();
```

I suppose you could do this:

```
var ugly = new Duck({ name: 'Ugly', role: 'Storytelling' });
ducks.add(ugly);
ugly.flyAway();
```

But is there any other direct way to do it? The docs don't really mention any way to, but that seems silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a later version of Backbone. [In this commit](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/commit/d9ac39fa64b712be99cf71ac537e5f25343fd847), Collection#set returns the freshly added models (and Collection#add calls Collection#set).